# Limited throughput of traffic originating from wireless access point

Tags: linux, networking, wifi, wifi-hotspot, hostapd

**Introduction:**

In an effort to avoid purchasing extraneous hardware, I've managed to configure my media center PC as a wireless access point using `hostapd` in bridge mode.

This works, but I'm experiencing an issue where any traffic that originates from the media center itself destined for a wireless host is significantly slower than traffic that is sent in the opposite direction or that simply passes through it from upstream.

I tested using several different protocols (iperf3 TCP/UDP, scp, samba, netcat TCP/UDP...) and all exhibit the same behavior, leading me to believe that the bridge configuration is at fault (i.e. it's a layer 2 issue).

[image: Network schematic]

**Test breakdown:**

```
1) WiFi 1     --> BridgeBox: ~300 Mbit/s
2) BridgeBox  -->    WiFi 1: ~15 Mbit/s TCP, ~150 Mbit/s UDP
3) Internet   -->    WiFi 1: ~200 Mbit/s (limited by ISP)
4) Wired 1    -->    WiFi 1: ~300 Mbit/s
5) WiFi 1     -->   Wired 1: ~300 Mbit/s
```

**Things I've tried:**

- Changing the bridge HW address to random (was cloned from wireless interface). No change.
- Changing the bridge HW address to match wired NIC. No change.
- Plugging in a USB NIC and adding it to the bridge. For whatever reason, even if nothing is connected to this interface, this causes test 2 bandwidth to jump to ~50 Mbit/s.

**Configuration:**

```
BridgeBox:~$ uname -a

Linux BridgeBox 4.15.0-43-generic #46~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Dec 7 13:31:08 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

---

```
BridgeBox:~$ cat /etc/network/interfaces

auto lo br0 wlp2s0

iface lo inet loopback

iface br0 inet static
  bridge_ports enp3s0
    address 192.168.12.2
    broadcast 192.168.12.255
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.12.1
    dns-nameserver 1.1.1.1
    dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8

iface wlp2s0 inet manual
    hostapd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
```

---

```
BridgeBox $ cat /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf

interface=wlp2s0
bridge=br0
driver=nl80211
logger_syslog=-1
logger_syslog_level=1
logger_stdout=-1
logger_stdout_level=2
ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ctrl_interface_group=0
beacon_int=100
dtim_period=2
max_num_sta=255
macaddr_acl=0
ignore_broadcast_ssid=0

### WMM
wmm_enabled=1
uapsd_advertisement_enabled=1
wmm_ac_bk_cwmin=4
wmm_ac_bk_cwmax=10
wmm_ac_bk_aifs=7
wmm_ac_bk_txop_limit=0
wmm_ac_bk_acm=0
wmm_ac_be_aifs=3
wmm_ac_be_cwmin=4
wmm_ac_be_cwmax=10
wmm_ac_be_txop_limit=0
wmm_ac_be_acm=0
wmm_ac_vi_aifs=2
wmm_ac_vi_cwmin=3
wmm_ac_vi_cwmax=4
wmm_ac_vi_txop_limit=94
wmm_ac_vi_acm=0
wmm_ac_vo_aifs=2
wmm_ac_vo_cwmin=2
wmm_ac_vo_cwmax=3
wmm_ac_vo_txop_limit=47
wmm_ac_vo_acm=0

### TX queue parameters
tx_queue_data3_aifs=7
tx_queue_data3_cwmin=15
tx_queue_data3_cwmax=1023
tx_queue_data3_burst=0
tx_queue_data2_aifs=3
tx_queue_data2_cwmin=15
tx_queue_data2_cwmax=63
tx_queue_data2_burst=0
tx_queue_data1_aifs=1
tx_queue_data1_cwmin=7
tx_queue_data1_cwmax=15
tx_queue_data1_burst=3.0
tx_queue_data0_aifs=1
tx_queue_data0_cwmin=3
tx_queue_data0_cwmax=7
tx_queue_data0_burst=1.5

ieee80211n=1
ht_capab=[LDPC][TX-STBC][RX-STBC1][DSSS_CCK-40][HT40+][HT40-]
ieee80211ac=1
vht_capab=[MAX-MPDU-11454][RXLDPC][SHORT-GI-80][TX-STBC-2BY1][RX-STBC-2BY1][MAX-A-MPDU-LEN-EXP7][RX-ANTENNA-PATTERN][TX-ANTENNA-PATTERN]
vht_oper_chwidth=1
vht_oper_centr_freq_seg0_idx=42
eapol_key_index_workaround=0
eap_server=0

#SSID and WPA settings
ssid=<xxxxxxx>
country_code=IL
hw_mode=a
channel=36
wpa=2
auth_algs=1
wpa_passphrase=<xxxxxxxx>
wpa_pairwise=TKIP CCMP
```

---

```
BridgeBox:-$ sudo lshw -C network | grep product
       product: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
```

Suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: You have not told us the brand and version of your wifi interface, and whether it is internal or USB, and form factor. Nano USB? Normal USB?

Comment: Thanks. I'm using an internal dual band WiFi adapter: QCA6174 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter